# Dynamics 365 - Lookup Field Dynamic Content in Outlook Email Template

Tags: outlook, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm currently creating email templates that will pull information off the sales order that the Outlook email is regarding. One field on the form is a Lookup field to another user in our system that will become the purchaser's main contact person after the order is fulfilled.

In my email template, I have a lot of dynamic content fields that are filling in information taken off that order form, but I'm trying to add another dynamic field that will pull the User contact information from the user Lookup field and autofill it into the email (i.e. their email address and phone number). I tried following the `{!EntityLogicalName:FieldLogicalName/@name;}` format, referencing the email address of the user in the lookup field, but nothing populates.

Is it possible to pull information on the associated record from a lookup field into an email template, or is that something that I'll have to have our reps manually fill out instead?